# Is there a word for releasing a fish or an animal into a (natural or artificial) habitat?

Tags: single-word-requests

I can always say "put a fish in a bowl" or "release a hare into the woods". But I wonder if there is a more specific word for this.

The point is that, after the action is taken, the animal will become less restricted and more happy than it was immediately before.

Examples:

- "The fisher took the goldfish from the hook and *put* it into a bottle." (Big enough and full of water. As unfortunate as it is, he may still fry the fish when he comes back home, but for the time she feels more comfortable than when she were hanging from the line.)
- When the puppy had grown up to become a wolf, the villager *released* it into the forest. (Tears flowing down his cheeks, but the wolf is going to be happier in the long run.)

Comment: "Return to the wild"

Comment: Sorry, Ignat; that’s too confusing. 

To "put a fish in a bowl" and to "release a hare into the woods" are opposites, though both are grammatical. Thus, there could never be anything like a more specific word for “this”.

Normal English never uses "The fisher” and if it did, the concept of  taking any fish from a hook and putting it into any bottle would be clearly opposite to releasing the hare into the woods.

Worse, Britons do not, ever fish for goldfish. It might not be against the law but it would be wholly abhorrent.

Answer (score 2):

**(Animal) repatriation** might be the word you are looking for. *Repatriation* is properly defined by [Meriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/repatriate) as:

> to restore or return to the country of origin, allegiance, or citizenship

The term *repatriation* is defined in [this journal article, called: *Relocation, Repatriation, and Translocation of Amphibians and Reptiles: Are They Conservation Strategies That Work?*](http://www.seaturtle.org/PDF/DoddCK_1991_Herpetologica.pdf) touches more on the subject. I have quoted their definition section below:

> "For the purposes of this paper, we define the release of individuals of a species into an area formally or currently occupied by that species a **repatriation**, whereas releases of individuals into geographic areas not historically occupied by that species are termed **translocations**. **Relocation** involves moving an animal or population of animals away from an area where they are immediately threatened (e.g., by development) to an area where they would be less prone to habitat loss; ideally, relocated animals should be moved to habitats where they historically occurred, but this is not always the case."

The quote is from the definition section of the paper (2nd page of the pdf) in that link (it is publicly available). [The paper has been cited over 500 times,
 according to Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar?um=1&ie=UTF-8&lr&cites=3190067118123160613) [For more information about the lead author](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C._Kenneth_Dodd_Jr.)

In the quote I have highlighted 3 terms, all of which are properly defined in the quote. So depending on the context one might choose one of those words.

[Backup link, should the paper be removed from the earlier link](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/279557416_Relocation_repatriation_and_translocation_of_amphibians_and_reptiles_Are_they_conservation_strategies_that_work)

Comment: People who care for injured wildlife speak of 'releasing' their recovered patients.

Comment: Repatriation presumably means much more than just releasing, I would suggest.

Comment: @NigelJ , I have actually found the paper I referred to, I have quoted their definition section, which properly defines three terms relating to the subject.

Answer (score 2):

'Release' and 'return' are the words used by the UK Government in regard to fish returned to rivers after being caught :

> Report a catch return
>
> how many fish you released

[UK Gov - Fishing and Hunting](https://www.gov.uk/catch-return)

'Release' is the word used by the UK Government for freeing animals or wildlife into the environment :

> Licence to release non-native wildlife and plants

[UK Gov - Licence to Release](https://www.gov.uk/nonnative-wildlife)

---

The two examples in the question are about different things. The fish in the example is taken home, not returned. The wolf cub is released back into its natural habitat.

But the heading question is about release and that is what is being answered here.

---

Relocation, repatriation and translocation are more complex and the paper indicated shows that it is not just about release and return but involves considerable efforts thereafter in care and husbandry.

Answer (score 1):

In the first instance, the OP is not *releasing* a goldfish into a bowl, they are *keeping* it in ***[captivity](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/captivity)***. It matters not the size, material or what form the enclosure is, the captured animal is not free to roam as it pleases.

The second is an example of *freeing* or [**releasing** an animal **back into the wild**](https://www.bbc.com/news/magazine-14791624) (its natural habitat).